# Material for Rainbow around Torus

Tags: materials, color

Is there a convenient way to make a rainbow material that varies smoothly along a torus? In the image below, I made a new emission material for each of the 32 segments along the major axis, changing the HSV hue by 1/32 each time. Clearly, you can still see bands of color; plus, it's labor intensive to make all of these materials, and challenging to edit afterwards.

[image: Torus with color bands]

Ultimately, I'd like to have the material's color spin around the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it this way: *Texture Coordinate (Object* output) > *Mapping > Gradient Texture (Radial mode) > ColorRamp* (that begins and ends with the same color) *> Emission > Material Output*. To make the color spin, use the *Mapping Z Rotation* value:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Just to add to Moonboot's nice answer.
*ColorRamp* can actually create the whole HSV spectrum for you :).

1. Set both sliders to **Red**
2. Set *ColorRamp* to *HSV > Far*
3. Done

[image]

Comment: I knew about clockwise, but never noticed the "Far" with red2red awesome :)

Comment: Yeah, I've learned that from [Chris Prenn](https://www.youtube.com/user/chrisprenn) some time ago. Don't think I've ever used it in an actual project though :).

Comment: I just wanted to use it in 2.79 and It looked like its not working, than I realised second Red has to be a slightly different color from 1/0/0 like 1/0/0.001 So thanks God for 2.9x polishing :)

Comment: @vklidu Oh that's a nice catch :).

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility for the lazies.

Add a Combine HSV node, plug in the hue and set the saturation and value to 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try replacing the Hue Saturation Value node (which changes an input color by those values) with a Combine HSV node. This lets you specify the Hue, Saturation and Value directly - just set a non-zero Saturation and Value and then use the gradient to drive the Hue.

Comment: @RichSedman Thanks for the tip :)