# How to create material that goes along curved mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, materials, modifiers

Excuse me, I have a cube, which has a curve modifier applied to it. I want to create a material that goes along the curved mesh, like this image below:

[image]

Here is my setup, which doesn't work:

[image]

Edit:
Setup with Curve ...

[image]

[image]

I hope my question makes sense.

Thank you so much
Stay safe :)

Comment: for a circular shape you could us a Gradient node in Radial mode: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200847/material-for-rainbow-around-torus ...  if the curve is a more complicated shape I guess you need to apply the array and curve modifiers and use the UV otuput socket of the Texture Coordinate?

Comment: What is the purpose to use a Cube? You can use just a Curve https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201466/2214

Comment: @Ahmed, do you use an Array modifier? If so, apply it, also, use the Generated output socket of the Texture Coordinate

Comment: You don't have in your node tree "Separate XYZ" node. If you want to go with Mapping node you have to setup there Rotate 90/135/0 and Scale X -3 or what ever that fits.

Comment: What is the question now? Seems to be OK, when you switch to Render mode view it is there as expected. Changing X Scale moves colours (also nice effect with plugged Y. With your "Constant I just noticed - distances between control point matters. If you r looking for even distribution independent on curve's control points you would have to use curve (with even distribution) deformed by curve (your current) I will post it later if needed. Please delete your comments, chatting is not allowed here. If you have something important move it via edit into your question post. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont mind you can use just a Curve.

**Shape**

- add Curve Circle, in edit mode Rotate 45, Duplicate and move 2.8 on X axis
- select all vertices switch handles to Free <kbd>V</kbd> and delete from both circles the center segment
- select end points and press <kbd>F</kbd> to connect

To get even distribution of colors you need to evenly distribut a curve's control points, that is not right now, but you can add another curve object - straight like, subdivide several times and deform this curve by previously shaped curve.

- Add some stickness to curve (tube) - go to *Properties editor > Object Data > Geometry >  Bevel >* **Depth**
- It is better to keep curve in type *Shape* *> 2D* and *Fill > None*
- Add Curve modifier (ensure origins both objects are at the same place)
- Moving along X axis will move along shape

**2.7x Material**

- Plug **UV** *Texture Coordinate* socket into *Separate XYZ* node
  and use X socket to lug into *ColorRamp*
- Enable under *Properties editor > Object Data > Texture Space >* **Use UV for mapping**.

To see material switch to Rendered type view mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**2.9x Material**
is like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201466/2214), you don't have to worry about UV in curve properties, it is set by default.

---

Notes:
Changing *X Location* will move gradient along curve.
[image]

Changing *X Scale* in Mapping node will change gradient scale.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer :)

Comment: @Ahmed Great it helped, just since you marekd as accepted, you should change the title to something neutral (mesh/curve) because you are asking a way with mesh and I aswered about curve. So dont get others confused. Thank you

Comment: amazing work flow but how do i use it with textures rather than colors.

Comment: Thanks :) ... Sorry I don't know what are you asking for? If you didnt find answer on this site ask a new Question. Image texture on curve is used in the same way, just without Separate XYZ node ... https://imgur.com/Sm82HRU